# How to select a name that contains the second letter is “s” using LINQ?

Tags: linq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSMNZ.png)

How select a name from DATABASE that contains the second letter is "s" using LINQ ?

Comment: The first rule of StackOverflow is: you do not post screenshots of code. The second rule of StackOverflow is: you do not post screenshots of code. Copy-paste *text* instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using lambda expressions:

```
      var str = new string[] { "tsr", "mrg", "d" };
      var result = str.Where(s => s.Length>1 && s[1] == 's');
```

The result variable will contain "tsr" value, and you are checking that the word have at least 2 characters otherwise an Exception would be thrown

Comment: i need LINQ Query similar to this  ------>>                                     public void  gridbnd()
       {
           tbl_user tu = new tbl_user();
            var query= from loc in udb.tbl_users 
                       where loc.name.Contains("_s%")
                       select loc;
            GridView1.DataSource = query;
            GridView1.DataBind();
                       

       }

Comment: @JithinJose This is an equivalent of that query: `var query = udb.tbl_users.Where(loc => loc.Name.Contains("_s%"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
from string str in myStrings
where str[1] == 's'
select str
```

Comment: I believe second character is `str[1]`. Also make sure string has at least two characters

Comment: i need LINQ Query similar to this  ------>>                                     public void  gridbnd()
       {
           tbl_user tu = new tbl_user();
            var query= from loc in udb.tbl_users 
                       where loc.name.Contains("_s%")
                       select loc;
            GridView1.DataSource = query;
            GridView1.DataBind();
                       

       }